# What exactly does MvcOptions.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes change?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, data-annotations, model-validation

As far as I understand it, value types implicitly have the `[Required]` attribute when `MvcOptions.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes` is set to `false`. But I frankly can't see any difference when I switch it between the two.

Furthermore, if i explicitly use the `[Required]` attribute on a non-nullable type, such as an `int`, it will **require** of me to set its value, rather than just hitting the endpoint without the given `int` parameter, which would be assigned a default value for its type - `0`.

So, to summarize:

1. If it implicitly adds the `[Required]` attribute, why does the explicit variant offer completely different functionality?
2. Is there any functional difference for enabling/disabling `MvcOptions.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes`? From what I can see, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: It's about "non-nullable reference types", `int` is value type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually haven't tried this setting yet, but I think the clue is in the name: SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeFor**NonNullableReferenceTypes**.

Sounds like it doesn't apply to value types.
It applies to non-nullable reference types.

As you said, a property with type `int` will always have a default value, the model validator doesn't know if the value was missing or if it was set to that.

However, if you enable C# 8 nullable reference types,
you could have properties like:

```
public string A { get; set; }

public string? B { get; set; }
```

Now with that setting set the `A` property gets the Required attribute.
It is still a reference type and can be null.
Thus the check makes sense.